# Mod remainder: if num is within 2 of a multiple of 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, division, modulus

I have to write a function to find if a given number (num) within 2 of a multiple of 10. I use modulus (%) to get the remainder, but it doesn't seem to be working quite right.  Help?

```
def nearten(num):
    if num%10<=2:
        return True
    elif num%10>2:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of all, you only checked to see whether the "ones" digit is 0, 1, or 2 -- you missed 8 and 9.

As a styling note, don't check a boolean expression and then hard-code the result you just found.  Your function, as currently written, reduces to this:

```
def nearten(num):
    return num%10 <= 2
```

Do you see how that works?  First of all, the **elif** check doesn't give you any new information: you already know that the result *must* be >2 when you get past the **if** condition.

Then, your statement reads like

```
if this condition is true, return true
otherwise, we know it's false; return false.
```

That's redundant.  You have a True/False value sitting right in your program's hand -- just return that one, instead of using a constant.

---

REPAIR ...

I'll leave this as an exercise for the student: "within" 2 means that you have to check both sides, so you have to pick up the cases where the ones digit is 8 or 9.  Can you write the expression to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ternary operator and check for if `num` is within 2 of multiple of 10:

```
def near_ten(num):
  return True if num%10<3 or num%10>7 else False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this code as:

```
def near_ten(num):    
    a = num % 10      
    return 2 >= a or 8 <= a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little help:

```
def near_ten(num):
    return num % 10 in [0,1,2,8,9,10]`
```

can also be:

```
return 0 <= (num % 10) <= 2 or 8 <= (num % 10) <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
def near_ten(num):
    return num%10 <= 2 or num%10 >= (10 - 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This method also works, just returning a bool value by using comparison operators in a single line to check both 'sides' of the cases:

```
def near_ten(num):
  return (num % 10 <= 2 or num % 10 >= 8)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def near_ten(num):
     if num%10<=2 :
         return True
     elif num%10 >=8:
         return True
     else:
         return False
```